# Outline Explorer Spyder 5 does not show the modules, cells and so on

Tags: spyder

I updated Spyder to the version 5 on Linux Mint 20.
The outline panel won't show modules, code cells etc. It used to work with Spyder4. Spyder3 shows outlines of the same scripts. Do you know how resolve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We're investigating why that happens. Some users have reported that the problem is fixed by deactivating Kite in `Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > General`.

Comment: yes, the outline panel works once I deactivated Kite. Thank you!

Comment: Disabling Kite didn't fix this issue for me. I've tried various combinations of the linting/completion options, but the results don't seem consistent. I restart Spyder to see if there's a difference and often there's not. Yet when I restart it later it does work. Or sometimes when it was working, I restart Spyder the next day and suddenly it's not working again. It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem in which the outline doesn't show anything except the comments that start with four ####.

I found the solution digging in the github and after I tried it, Outline panel worked like a charm:

*Just make sure to have a **__init__.py** file in the location of the script or file you'r working with.*  It can be empty, but it needs to be present. After that, the outline started to show all the functions, cells, classes, etc.

I cant remember if I needed to restart Spyder (I don't think so) but at least give it a restart if the __init__ file doesn't solve the issue.

Good luck

Comment: This did it for me! It also fixes the *go to definition*.

Comment: Adding `if __name__ == '__main__': pass` at my script fixed it too.

Comment: @mixophyes It solves it only for the file you wrote it ? Or it solves it as well for all scripts in a same foldet ?

Comment: Well... it resolved it.... permanently?? I commented those lines out and I cannot replicate the problem either in that script or any other in the same or different folders after restarting Spyder. Go figure?

Comment: This worked. I had to reopen the file I was working on. IMHO this is a bug in Spyder that should be fixed. For me the error also did only occur in subdirectories. The main directory of the project was not affected.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, outline showed no structure.

Spyder 5 was being really slow as I was editing. I worked out it was the completion and linting churning away as I was typing so I started turning features off. I turned it all off and the outline stopped working. So I resent and went about turning things off systematically.

Finally got a responsive Spyder and outline workign with just "Enable basic linting" and "Enable code completion and basic linting in the editor" turned on

Comment: I'm having this exact issue! I have a very large script for which the outline is crucial to quickly navigating, but Spyder was extremely slow since the upgrade. I disabled everything except the two you mentioned above, but my outline still only shows the script name and no cell names.

Answer (score 0):

There were already bugfixing attempts going on at [GitHub](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15139)
and it seemed as if the root cause had been on Kite and the problem resolved on Spyder v5.0.2. Whereas in my understanding it came back in v5.0.3 in which I also experienced it.

Downgrading Spyder to v4.2.5 via

`conda install spyder=4.2.5`

helped in my case.